# File default location

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

Why the program search the file:

```
    File FILE_PATH = new File("‪‪C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\DbWord.txt");
    System.out.println(FILE_PATH.exists());
    System.out.println(FILE_PATH.getAbsoluteFile());
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(fIn);
```

at: C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyDatabase\‪‪C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt

How can i counteract the default location?

**If something in this post not good, please tell me and no negative vote.**

Thanks!

why negative votes??????????????? whats your problems??????????

Comment: @Ofir question is not clear

Comment: @dex hey, I try to pull out from the file that place in :C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\DbWord.txt 
but the prograam writes that the file not found and it write me that file: C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyDatabase\‪‪C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt
i mean the program trying to search the file in this path.. why?

Comment: @dex i edited my command. thanks :)

Comment: I guess you have added android in wrong way, because android don't have windows type file system. Please remove android and ask this question with tag java, Netbeans , Java applet

Comment: @dex oh ok i did it.. thanks.. and can you vote up? or help me?

Comment: Have you tried forward slashes?

Comment: @DaDaDom thank you on command. It change the path to project path + the path desired. Do you know maybe how can I change it? and - maybe can you please vote up my question? it minus 1 and after this i get ban always... and thank for your help ..!!

Comment: What specifical line is producing the following `C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyDatabase\‪‪C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt`? I have a hunch that you're misreading your stack trace.

Comment: @Keith look one command up .. and why negative vote man?

Comment: If I "look up one command",  I see `Scanner reader = new Scanner(fIn);` Provide more of the entire stack trace in the question

Comment: @Keith i meant it : "thank you on command. It change the path to project path + the path desired. Do you know maybe how can I change it? and - maybe can you please vote up my question? it minus 1 and after this i get ban always... and thank for your help ..!! "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check your error details. You might have seen something like the below error. Actually the program is not searching for the file `"C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyDatabase\‪‪C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt"`, it is trying to locate the file `"C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt"` which does not exists in your machine. You are seeing `"C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyDatabase\‪‪C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt"` along with the error because you have already used `System.out.println(FILE_PATH.getAbsoluteFile());` statement in your code.

```
false
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪‪C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyDatabase\‪‪C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt
    at com.stackoverflow.answer.SimpleFileHelper.main(SimpleFileHelper.java:17)
```

Hope you are clear now.

There are three main chances where a `FileNotFoundException` may be thrown.

1. The named file does not exist.
2. The named file is actually a directory not file.
3. The named file cannot be opened for reading due to some reason.

The first two reasons are unlikely based on your description, please check the third point using `file.canRead()` method.

If the test above returns true, I would suspect the following:

You might have forgotten to explicitly throw or catch the potential exception (i.e., `FileNotFoundExcetion`). If you work in an IDE, you should have got some complaint from the compiler. But I suspect you didn't run your code in such an IDE.

Try the following code and see if the exception would be gone:

```
package com.stackoverflow.answer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleFileHelper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File FILE_PATH = new File("C:/Users/home/Desktop/DbWord.txt");
        System.out.println(FILE_PATH.exists());
        System.out.println(FILE_PATH.getAbsoluteFile());
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(fIn);
    }
}
```

Comment: you right, but th file: C:\Users\home\Desktop\DbWord.txt is exists on my computer.. what need i do? and why always negative vote ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: ok thanks.. you know maybe why the file is "empty" while he contains hebrew latters? thanks again..